# how to check enum values and return corresponding enum

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, enumerate

my schema is as below

```
"statusCode": {  
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["A", "T", "U"]
        }
```

I am trying to write a method which would check for the code and return corresponding enum.

```
private void updateStatusCode(Event event) {
        Enum code = null;
        switch(event.getStatusCode()) {
            case A:
            code = ["A"];
            break;
            case T:
            break;
            case U:
            break;
            default:

        }
         return code;

    }
```

event.getStatusCode valid values are: A , T , U. Now I need to check for these codes and return enum based on the codes. I tried the above but it gives me error on code = ["A"]. error states below.

```
Syntax error on token "=", Expression expected after this token
```

How do i fix this ? I am new to java. any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: `["A"]` is not a valid Java expression. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Additionally ... I am not understanding what your code and your shown JSON snippet have to do in common.

Comment: statusCode is enum. its values can be A, T or U. I need to check for these values and return the enum with corresponding values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do here but you misunderstood the concept of enum. In the comment you said statusCode is an enum but it isn't an enum it's in a json format and not a real Java expression.As I said I don't know what you are trying to achieve but you can modify your code like below .

first create an enum

```
enum StatusCode{
   A,
   B,
   U

}
```

if you want to get the string equivalent of the enum values you use the following code

```
enum StatusCode{
   A("A"),
   T("T"),
   U("U");
   String code;
   public StatusCode(String code){
     this.code=code;
   }
   String getCode(){
     return code;
   }
  }
```

and then modify your method like this

```
private void updateStatusCode(Event event) {
        StatusCode code;
        switch(event.getStatusCode()) {
            case A:
            code = StatusCode.A;
            break;
            case T:
            code = StatusCode.T;
            break;
            case U:
            code = StatusCode.U;
            break;
        }
         return code;

    }
```

you can get the string value of an enum as

```
StatusCode code=StatusCode.A;
String strCode=code.getCode();
```

Comment: Well the complexity of having a constructor with a "code" field is rather usefless here, as the String version is built in the enum itself through the methods `name()` (or `toString()`) and `valueOf()`

Comment: Yes but you provided that solution already I want to give him a solution if he want to bind a name that is longer for examle if status code A stands for ```"Abcd"``` and also if he want to add more information about the status codes like status description.Using constructor for enum is not complex at all.

Comment: All right then ;)

Answer (score 2):

You seem confused about how enumerations works in Java. An `enum` is basically a list of well-known values that can be assigned to an instance of the enum class. It encompasses the methods to convert from/to String as frequently required. `Enum` is the superclass of them all, but you usually don't need to use it directly.

For instance, let's say I've got the following definition:

```java
enum StatusCode {
 A,
 T,
 U
}
```

This means that an object of the class `StatusCode` can only have the values `A`, `T` or `U`.
And to convert, I'd use :

```java
String fromString = "A";
StatusCode sc = StatusCode.valueOf(fromString); //gives sc = StatusCode.A
String backToString = sc.name(); //gives backToString = "A"
```

Learn more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html